# Where could I find the dll/exe/process that handles the Bluetooth tray icon?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, taskbar, desktop-customization, notification-area

Where could I find the exe/process/dll that handles this colored tray icon of Bluetooth tray icon.

[image]

I am very customized person, so I want to customize it, break it open and replace those resources with my redesigned ones to make that Bluetooth icon in line with that other Windows 10 tray icons. Where I could find it? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

A BT icon is present in `%systemroot%\system32\netshell.dll`, but it looks a bit too dark. The standard tray icon is probably the one in `%systemroot%\system32\btpanui.dll`.

Comment: That's it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Bluetooth files are found here on my computer, for example:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Bluetooth
```

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Bluetooth\Resources\Bluetooth.ico` should be the file you're looking for.

Also, as [@Magnus](https://superuser.com/users/731090/magnus)
has pointed out, the folder Intel will only be Intel if Intel manufactured your Bluetooth module. You can most likely go to Device Manager (devmgmt.msc) to determine the manufacturer of your Bluetooth chip.

Good luck with your customization!

Comment: Although they should be somewhere under `C:\Program Files (x86)` or `C:\Program Files`, if the chipset supplying the Bluetooth functionality is from a different manufacturer, it won't be under the sub-folder `Intel`. A search on "Bluetooth" will most likely find it. Or you could start the task manager and look for a process with the same icon, then right-click and "Open file location" to jump right to it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I've tried all what you're saying. I even searched Windows for "bluetooth" yea did show up some, and even the Task Manager trick, but ends me customizing the Bluetooth context menu option on Send to... not the tray. I also can't find the Bluetooth under Intel. Mine's not showing the real manufacturer but it' said HP Integrated Bluetooth. Could be manufactured by HP? Is there any directory you have in mind where this is hiding?

Comment: I guarantee it's under somewhere in there. We'll continue trying to help as long as we have the time and you have the patience.

Answer (score 0):

i'm very customized person too, bro ^^

BT tray icon contains in %WINDIR%\System32\bthprops.cpl
[click-for-photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFHUd.jpg)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/10hkFbHqn_htbcBRvuCjpmhRPMMK5DV-P/view?usp=sharing file with my white-style icon

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).